# Why does the display language for Simplified Chinese resort to ISO code?

Tags: java, locale, cjk, iso

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;

public final class ForeignTextDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Locale locale = new Locale("TW");
        System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE));
        locale = new Locale("CN");
        System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE));
    }

}
```

When I run the program above, I get the following output:

```
契維文
cn
```

But, if I change the second locale to `locale = new Locale("ZH");`, I get the desired output of:

```
契維文
中文
```

Why is this? **What I really want is the display language for Simplified Chinese**. Is "ZH" just that?

Comment: The single argument constructor is the *language*, not the country. The country is 2nd in the two-argument constructor. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#constructor.summary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just "cn" isn't the locale, the full local is "zh_CN" to differentiate with "tw_CN".

See the list of [supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html).

```
locale1 = new Locale("zh", "cn")
println locale1.getDisplayLanguage(locale1)
println locale1.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE)
println locale1.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE)
println locale1.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.TAIWAN)
println locale1.getDisplayCountry(locale2)
println locale1.country

println ""

locale2 = new Locale("tw", "cn")
println locale1.getDisplayLanguage(locale2)
println locale2.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE)
println locale2.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE)
println locale2.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.TAIWAN)
println locale2.getDisplayCountry(locale2)
println locale2.country
```

Comment: From the list of supported locales.

Comment: @mre Hmm, yeah, you're right, sorry--I think I got that from a previous JDK's list of locales, and I guess it's still supported.

Comment: @mre You know how it is with Taiwan and the mainland; I guess Sun/Oracle is hedging their bets ;)

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation that gave you "tw_CN"?

Comment: @mre Now I can't find it; all I can find is "zh_CN" and "zh_TW"; maybe I mixed it up when I typed it in... not sure. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mre Hmm. What JDK version are you using?

Comment: @mre I think the confusion is from the `Locale` constructor which takes language/country as separate params, not combined with the underscore. Adding code to answer (Groovy, but same difference.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Javadoc for `java.util.Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29), the single-arg constructor for `Locale()` expects an [ISO 639-1 language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).  The ISO 639-1 language code for Chinese is "ZH".

What you are actually providing with both your "TW" and "CN" strings are the [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) Country Codes for Taiwan and China.